# Running a custom script/exe through the nsclient++ web server

Tags: monitoring, nsclient++

I have nsclient++ installed on my windows 8 machine and I have include a custom .net exe to do some application monitoring for me.  The nsclient++ has no issues running the exe and send the result to my nagios server.  That part works.

I also turned on nsclient web server on the windows machine and that works too.  I can run Check_cpu, Check_disk, etc. through the web and it's wonderful (rock'on Michael Medin!).

However, I want to be able to run my custom exe through the web server just like the other modules that you can run like Check_memory, Check_cpu, etc.  As it is, my custom exe is not showing up on the web server UI.

I went through nsclient++ website and there is an API document nsclient core functionalities but couldn't find an API specific for the web server part.  Since I'm doing this in .Net I'm hoping that all I have to do is to implement an interface (or something like that) to interact with nsclient web server. Or may be even something simpler.

Question
How can I include my custom exe to be part of the list of checks that one can perform **manually** through the web using nsclient++?  If there are any code samples out there that would bring tears to my eyes.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The web UI is not magical (and neither are built-in checks) so if the command is available via for instance NRPE then it is also available through the WEB UI.

So this should be the way to go: https://docs.nsclient.org/howto/external_scripts.html#adding-a-script

```
[/modules]
CheckExternalScripts=enabled

[/settings/external scripts/scripts]
foo=scripts\foo.bat
```

Comment: Thanks you. I already added all my scripts an are working fine and I"m getting the result on the server.  However,  I'm using NSCA.  The NSCA doc doesn't appear to be here.  It says not found.  https://docs.nsclient.org/howto/wiki/doc/usage/nagios/nsca  Do you know when this will be updated/created?

Comment: https://docs.nsclient.org/tutorial/nagios/nsca.html this one?

Comment: Thanks again.  My issue is not solved.  But that's okay. Mr. Medin, you have already done enough with your wonderful -- free -- tools. For dignity and decency sake, I'm going to concentrate on having my boss buy a support package from you.  Thanks again Michael.